# converting Row to json error when validating

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I want to send the output of the model to mqtt. when I converted it to son and dumped into mqtt the data was not getting pushed. when I debugged my code, I found problem when converting to son. I am trying to validate

```
[{
    'Date': '21-04-2020 15:00:33',
    'coil_addr': '1',
    'Status': '0.0'
}]
```

but it is throwing error

```
Error: Parse error on line 1:
[{  'Date': '21-04-2020 
---^
Expecting 'STRING', '}', got 'undefined'
```

It was working fine, but now this error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please clarify what you are trying to achieve? What exactly are you trying to validate?

Comment: i have to dump this json to mqtt.. but it not getting sent.. this is basically a output which I want to send to mqtt.. so when I validated above output in jsonlint.com it is throwing above error

Comment: Edit your question to clarify.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace single quotes (') with double quotes (") because the JSON standard requires double quotes.